# realloc vs linked list : no random access

Tags: c

I'm programming an application which contain that kind of structure:

```
typedef struct Triangle{
    struct Triangle* Neighbor[3];

    some other datas...
} Triangle;
```

Each triangle has 3 neighbors. Note that triangle are doubly connected as the neighbors of a triangle contain the current triangle as its neighbors.
My algorithm will walk through the graph, sometimes adding a new triangle, sometimes deleting one. It begins with 1 triangle and at the end, we will have **N** triangles.

I know in advance that **M** is the average of **N** and we also know that **N** is rarely greater than **2M** (5% of time maybe)

---

to give you a better view, this code update the neighbors of a Triangle.

```
void update_triangle_neighbors(Triangle* T, Triangle* oldptr, Triangle* newptr){
    if(T->Neighbor[0]==oldptr)
        T->Neighbor[0] = newptr;
    else if(T->Neighbor[1]==oldptr)
        T->Neighbor[1] = newptr;
    else
        T->Neighbor[2] = newptr;
}
```

---

I have two choices:

- **1:** Allocate a **2M** array of Triangle at once and reallocate 1.5x previous size if the array is already full when we want to add a new triangle.

  To remove a triangle of which I have the pointer `*toRemove`, I must:

  - **1.1:** I update the Neighbors:

    ```
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        update_triangle_neighbors(&(toRemove->Neighbor[i]), toRemove, NULL)
    ```
  - **1.2:** update the neighbor of last Triangle to be linked to `*toRemove` and not to the last Triangle as previously

    ```
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        update_triangle_neighbors(&(LastTriangle->Neighbor[i]), LastTriangle, toRemove)
    ```
  - **1.3:** copy the `*LastTriangle` into `*toRemove` and decrease a variable that contain the size of the array
- **2:** Use *malloc* and *free* every time I have to add or delete a Triangle.
  To remove a triangle of which I have the pointer `*toRemove`, I must:

  - **2.1:** refer to **1.1.**
  - **2.2** free the memory : `free(toRemove)`

---

The advantages of method **1** is that it only does one malloc 95% of time and that it may improve spatial locality by only allocating one big array. The disadvantages is that the deletion is a bit complicated and we will have to do a `realloc` if there are too much Triangles.

What do you think is the best idea ? (it's for a university project and I don't know if I will have the time to implement both and do a benchmark)

**TL;DR: preallocated linked list or normal linked list when you nearly know the size of the array but you don't know have to do random access.**

---

EDIT: thanks all for your great advices ! I answered my own question here after but I'm still open for suggestion :)

Comment: What is the order of magnitude of `M` or `N`? Are you creating a hundred triangles? a million?

Comment: In my opinion, I wouldn't worry too much about where the memory is going to be located, or how long it's going to take to do lots of allocating vs allocating once.  Especially for a student project, I think straight forward is the best approach and keep it as simple as you can.  Therefore, I'd probably suggest option 2.

Comment: it's for a triangulation program. There is a relationship with the number of points you want and the average number of triangle. The upper bound is only limited by memory and the lower bound is zero. It is often in the order of the million

Comment: KISS until you really can't.

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++.

Comment: Do you have any strong evidences that not keep it simple (KISS) will lead to performance problems? I would suggest to make allocate/free functions that just do malloc/free (you can declare them `inline`) and if it is too slow replace them with a more complex allocation system.

Comment: No, I don't have any evidence, it's just that my teacher talked about using a big memory allocation and reallocate if needed. Therefore I began with this method but I'm thinking right now it may not be the best solution.

Comment: if you really want to play with that you can managed your own "allocator". It as a "init", "allocate", "free" API, and inside you can do what you want: direct malloc/free, or allocating a large block, giving/freeing them with reallocation on any criteria you want. It even exists libs that do that.

Comment: Will you be accessing the triangles more often than inserting new ones?  If accessing occurs more frequently, you may want to use a data structure that provides quick access.  Similarly, if you are adding and removing triangles more often, use a data structure that has fast insertion and removal attributes.

Comment: From the code you've presented, `realloc()` won't work.  Given `T array[X]`, if `array[N].neighbor[M]` points to another member of `array`, calling `realloc(array, newSize)` could result in `array` being stored at another location in memory, thus invalidating all pointers into the original location of `array`

Comment: oh, yeah, that's true. I could save the index in the array in place of each pointer, but that would complicate the 1st implementation even more.
Thank you for pointing this out !!

Answer (score 1):

As [Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle) pointed out, `realloc()` won't work because it might change the location in memory of the whole array and all the `Triangle*` pointers would point to a wrong adress. I could replace the `Triangle*` pointers by indexes in my array but that would complicate all my stuff, especially for debugging.

Therefore, I think I'm gonna go with the second approach which is by far the simplest one. In addition, there is no evidence at all that the first approach can be faster.

---

### Speedup

If I want to speed up my program a little bit when it is working well, I still can implement my 'own malloc' in this way (as [hexasoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5440452/hexasoft) suggested):

- Allocate a 2M array of Triangle at the beginning
- for each malloc call:

  - if there is still space in that array, give a pointer to the free space
  - if there is no space left, just allocate somewhere else (in 95% of cases, the program will terminate without this happening even once)

> why do you even think of doing a realloc in this case ?

I really don't know, thinking back it was really stupid. Locality is not that much important here and I was ready to move mountains just to gain a little bit of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `calloc` to allocate (it zero's the memory for you),
and free to free... if you are running on anything like a modern OS, there shouldn't be much penalty...

if in your study you discover you need to do something else, then look into options there, but I consider realloc a code smell no matter what, and it is really bad to use if you have more than one pointer to a chunk of memory...